# Intermittent value from if statement via html input range

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I have an if statement that sometimes returns the correct value and sometimes does not.

The problem can be reproduced using the snippet below:

To reproduce move the slider to various values. (see screenshot)

A new row is appended to the table on each change.
Notice that sometimes the result is false.

Why it does not return true every time?

[image: sample screenshot of results]

```js
$("#inputRange").change(function() {
  $("#slideValue").val(this.value);
  if (isValidRange(this.value)) {
    console.log("Yes");
  } else {
    console.log("No");
  }
});

function isValidRange(range) {
  // get min and max value of input range
  var sliderMin = $("#inputRange").attr("min");
  var sliderMax = $("#inputRange").attr("max");
  var bResult = false;

  if (range >= sliderMin) {
    if (range <= sliderMax) {
      bResult = true;
    } else {
      bResult = false;
    }
  } else {
    bResult = false;
  }

  //  build new table row
  var sRow = "<tr><td>" + sliderMin + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + sliderMax + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + range + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + bResult + "</td></tr>";

  $("#tableData").append(sRow);

  return bResult;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="slideValue">Value</label>
    <input id="slideValue" type="input" class="form-control col-2" />
  </div>
  <div id="sampleDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="inputRange" type="range" min="1" max="21" step="1" value="200" data-thumbwidth="20">
    </div>
  </div>

  <table id="tableData" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Min</td>
      <td>Max</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>result</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: I tried rewriting the if statement using Ternary, but that doesn't fix the problem. `bResult = range >= sliderMin ? (range <= sliderMax ? true : false) : false;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values of `sliderMin` and `sliderMax` in your code are evaluated as `string` instead of `int`. That is, `sliderMin == "1"` and `sliderMax == "21"`.

Hence, when input value is `"3"`, `range <= sliderMax` evaluates to false because `"3"` is larger than `"2"` (first character of `"21"`).

To fix this, I'd convert `string` to `int` using `parseInt`.

```js
$("#inputRange").change(function() {
  $("#slideValue").val(this.value);
  if (isValidRange(parseInt(this.value))) { // parseInt here
    console.log("Yes");
  } else {
    console.log("No");
  }
});

function isValidRange(range) {
  // get min and max value of input range
  var sliderMin = parseInt($("#inputRange").attr("min")); // parseInt here
  var sliderMax = parseInt($("#inputRange").attr("max")); // parseInt here
  var bResult = false;

  if (range >= sliderMin) {
    if (range <= sliderMax) {
      bResult = true;
    } else {
      bResult = false;
    }
  } else {
    bResult = false;
  }

  //  build new table row
  var sRow = "<tr><td>" + sliderMin + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + sliderMax + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + range + "</td>";
  sRow += "<td>" + bResult + "</td></tr>";

  $("#tableData").append(sRow);

  return bResult;
}
```

```css
.container {
  margin:15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="slideValue">Value</label>
    <input id="slideValue" type="input" class="form-control col-2" />
  </div>
  <div id="sampleDiv">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input id="inputRange" type="range" min="1" max="21" step="1" value="200" data-thumbwidth="20">
    </div>
  </div>

  <table id="tableData" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>Min</td>
      <td>Max</td>
      <td>value</td>
      <td>result</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I should have been able to spot that.  If only I had thought about checking the data type.

Comment: The documentation clearly says that the value is a string. `The value attribute contains a DOMString which contains a string representation of the selected number.`